# Devise configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I currently want to make a login with devise. On top of email and password I want to have an username. I generated the migration:

```
class AddUsernameToBuyer < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :buyers, :username, :string
    add_index :buyers, :username, unique: true
  end
end
```

I also added username in the sign-up view:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :username %> <br />
   <%= f.text_field :username %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @validatable %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

And I put in application controller username as a permited parameter:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username) }
    end

    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

When I try to sign up I am redirected as I should be to: `http://localhost:3000/buyers/sign_up`

After I fill in the details I hit sign up and I want myself to be redirected to the root_page. However devise redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/buyers` and it tells me that I can't have a blank username even though I added it.

How can I change this behavior/fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect you need to put `after_sign_up_path_for` to `RegistrationsController`. Create it first to override `Devise`'s native controller.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: yes sorry I did that and I forgot to change it in the post . I will do that right now. The error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate url in your `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)`. Try below code.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  root_path
end
```

Comment: same problem, i am redirected to /buyers

Comment: And I did change the method in after_sign_up not sign_in because that was my problem but still the same